# How to add a scene to a view in mainwindow.cpp?

Tags: c++, qt

Doing searches this is what I find and placed in "main.cpp":

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsView view(&scene);
```

But I need something like the following and placed within "mainwindow.cpp" :

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
view->addScene(&scene); //need something like this
```

---

This works in main and displays a "yellow" background.  But when I make the changes with setScene in mainwindow.cpp... than the yellow background does not appear.

main.cpp

```
 QGraphicsScene scene;
 QGraphicsView view(&scene);

 view.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
 view.setBackgroundBrush(Qt::yellow);
 view.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
 view.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::BoundingRectViewportUpdate);
 view.setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
 view.setWindowTitle(QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP(QGraphicsView, "Colliding Mice"));
 view.resize(1000, 800);
 view.show();
```

---

mainwindow.cpp  : no yellow background

```
 QGraphicsScene scene;
 QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
 view->setScene(&scene);

 view->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
 view->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::yellow);
 view->setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
 view->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::BoundingRectViewportUpdate);
 view->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
 view->setWindowTitle(QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP(QGraphicsView, "Colliding Mice"));
 view->resize(1000, 800);
 view->show();
```

Comment: view->setScene(&scene);

Comment: In response to the updated code, you need to dynamically allocate the scene, else it will get deleted as soon as it goes out of scope; QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer from @JaminGrey, you can call the QMainWindow function setCentralWidget, passing the QGraphicsView object to add it to the QMainWindow.

If you're not using QMainWindow, call the QGraphicsView function show(). Note that you also need to add objects to the QGraphicsScene in order to see something.

Ensure that QGraphicsScene is dynamically allocated before being added to the QGraphicsView as the view takes a pointer to the scene.

Comment: Please update your question with the latest code, taking into account the answers both I and @JaminGrey have provided, then we'll be able to help you further.

Comment: with your added "In response to the updated code, you need to dynamically allocate the scene, else it will get deleted as soon as it goes out of scope; QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene; " this works...thx

Comment: @jdl I missed this latest comment and added an additional answer not realizing your problem was "solved". Unfortunately, however, it's not fully solved (even if it appears to work), because your memory is not being deallocated, giving you a memory leak. Merlin069 is absolutely right that you need to dynamically allocate it! But you also must have a plan to deallocate it, or to let Qt deallocate it. But you aren't currently doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You want '**[setScene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsview.html#setScene)**' not 'addScene'. Since there can only ever be one scene set to a view at a time, 'set' is the proper word for the function name, implying that it replaces whatever scene was previously there. 'add' would imply that the old scene(s) remain present even while the new scene is added, which isn't the case with `QGraphicsView`.

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
view->setScene(&scene); //<--- The function name you want.
```

Ofcourse, your QGraphicsView needs to actually be set to your main window.
If you want it to fill the entire main window, use:

```
this->setCentralWidget(view); //Assuming 'this' is the QMainWindow widget.
```

As @Merlin069 advises.

If you don't want it to fill the entire window, but want other stuff as well, you should add a layout to the main window widget, and add the view to the layout:

```
//Create the layout.
QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout;

//Add widgets to the layout.
horizontalLayout->addWidget(sidepanelOnTheLeft);
horizontalLayout->addWidget(view);
horizontalLayout->addWidget(sidepanelOnTheRight);

//Set the layout to the widget that owns it.
this->centralWidget()->setLayout(horizontalLayout);
```

Qt's documentation is very good. You should definitely bookmark:

### [Qt Documentation: Class Index](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/classes.html)

Comment: A Window shows up but nothing draws on it(when done in mainwindow.cpp).  But it draws when done in "main.cpp"

Comment: @jdl: Updated the post. If you need more help, could you upload main.cpp and mainwindow.cpp to [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/), so we can see your code and give more specificcly-tailored advice?

Answer (score 2):

(*New answer, because it's answering a different issue as the OP updated the question*)

Your problem is that `QGraphicsScene scene;` is created locally to the function (that I assume is the MainWindow constructor).

This means it goes:

```
function()
{
   QGraphicsScene scene; //Creates the scene.
   QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(); //Creates the view
   view->setScene(&scene); //Adds the scene to the view, but *the view does not take ownership*

   //...other stuff...

   view->show(); //Show the view.

} //<--- The scene gets destroyed because it was local, and when being destroyed, removes itself from the view.
```

Instead, QGraphicsScene should be dynamically allocated, and 'owned' by the 'this' pointer of main (or else a member-variable of main):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
   QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this /* Gives ownership to MainWindow */);
   QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this /* Gives ownership to MainWindow */);
   view->setScene(scene);

   view->setWhateverSettingsYouWant();
   scene->setWhateverSettingsYouWant();

   //Tell the MainWindow that you want the view to be *inside* the MainWindow.
   //Also gives ownership to the MainWindow (again, but it won't hurt anything).
   this->setCentralWidget(view);
}
```

`QWidgets` (and `QObjects`, which `QWidgets` inherit) have a parent->child hierarchy. When a parent is destroyed, it frees every child as well. **This is important**. If you just 'new' stuff, they are never deleted! So they have to be 'owned' by a parent, so the parent can delete them when the parent itself is destroyed.